# Trigger on Text in TextBox

Tags: wpf, triggers

I have this code:

```
<Style x:Key="qwe" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="qwe">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But when I have "qwe" in TextBox, It is still enabled. 
What is wrong?

Comment: its working fine show your TextBox xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You referenced the style on some TextBox, right?

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource qwe}"/>
```

Works for me...

Make sure you don't [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) the trigger by setting IsEnabled on the TextBox itself.